# CakePHP simple retrieve data

Tags: sql, cakephp, find

I can't handle with retrieving data from model. My table is :

```
CREATE TABLE grades(
id INT NOT NULL,
value nvarchar(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT grades(id, value) VALUES
(1,N'A'),
(2,N'F'),
(8,N'B+'),
(10,N'C')
```

and i tried in controller

```
var $uses = array( 'Grade');

function index(){
    $this->Grade->read();
    $this->set ( 'grade', $this->Grade->data );
    $this->set ( 'res' );
    $res = $this->Grade->find(array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => 2)
            ));

}
```

and in view

```
<?php debug($res);?>
```

returns array(). I need it to work like 'SELECT * FROM grades WHERE id = 2;'

I need it to return something like~

```
2, F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it simply works, when I erase line

```
$this->Grade->read();
```

and it solved my problem, no one knows.

Answer (score 3):

```
function index(){
    $res = $this->Grade->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => 2)
    ));
    $this->set('res', $res);
}
```

I highly suggest you go through the [CakePHP Book's Tutorials & Examples](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html). There are so many things wrong or strange with your code that I'm not going to even try to explain it all, but above is how you could find a `Grade` based on an `id`.

Comment: generally you didnt help me. I needed to know how to basically withdraw data, and you returning me to whole book. I read it before and i didnt find solution, then i asked here. I dont have time to read and learn all cookbook. THZ!

Comment: It honestly sounds like you just need to hire an actual developer.  If you can't spend 20 minutes going through the tutorial (as you most certainly have not based on what I see in your code).  Then, after being provided the exact answer, you decline it's help... yeah.  Not trying to be rude, but I would suggest http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ where you can look for a developer to hire.

Comment: There are so many things wrong or strange with your code that I'm not going to even try to explain it all. Pretty please, follow Dave's advice.

Comment: @PaulDew If you want to learn how to use CakePHP then read the book. There’s a section specifically on [retrieving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html). You’re lucky people took the time to answer; I’m voting to close this question: “Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.**”

Answer (score 0):

Your find-statement looks good, but you don't set it for the view

```
$this->set ( 'res' );
```

Try:

```
$res = $this->Grade->find(array(
'conditions' => array('id' => 2)
        ));

$this->set('res', $res);
```

With that you do your find, save the result in `$res` and give it to the view using the `set()`.

Comment: still returning array() :-(